# Retrieve custom header details from soap request developed using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws

I have developed soap request using spring boot where my soap request contain custom herders inside "" section of "soapenv:Header". I am facing issue to retrieve details passed inside "" section. There are no Exception but what I am receiving are all empty properties value of RequestHeader object at backend

My soap request looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://com/schema/OrderRequest" xmlns:ns="http://com/schema/RequestHeader">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <ns:RequestHeader>
        <ns:name>Name1</ns:name>
       </ns:RequestHeader>>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
    .... no issue to retrieve body information
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I an tring to retrieve header section using below code

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "OrderRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<OrderResponse> createOrder(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<OrderRequest>
            createWorkOrderRequestCplxType, @SoapHeader("{http://com/schema/RequestHeader/2/0}RequestHeader")SoapHeaderElement requestHeader) {

        log.info("Start createWorkOrder :");

    
        try{
            Source bodySource = requestHeader.getSource();
            DOMSource bodyDomSource = (DOMSource) bodySource;
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestHeader.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
            RequestHeader requestH = (RequestHeader) unmarshaller.unmarshal(bodyDomSource);
            log.info("activity name from request header : {}",requestH.getName); //This value is getting empty
        }catch (JAXBException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        
        }
  }
```

Can you please help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was tried multiple ways but didn't find direct solution to get Java object of RequesHeader directly in PayloadRoot method. Hence able to manage with below alternate approach:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "OrderRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<OrderResponse> createOrder(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<OrderRequest>
            createWorkOrderRequestCplxType, MessageContext messgeContext) {

        
        RequestHeader requestHeader = prepareRequestHeader(messageContext);
    
    
  }
  
  
  private RequestHeader prepareRequestHeader(MessageContext messageContext) {
   
    RequestHeader requestHeader = new RequestHeader();
    SoapHeader soapHeader = ((SoapMessage) messageContext.getRequest()).getSoapHeader();
    Iterator<?> elementIter = soapHeader.examineAllHeaderElements();
    while (elementIter.hasNext()) {

        Object element = elementIter.next();
        if (!(element instanceof SoapHeaderElement)) {
            continue;
        }

        Result result = ((SoapHeaderElement) element).getResult();
        if (!(result instanceof DOMResult)) {
            continue;
        }

        NodeList nodeList = ((DOMResult) result).getNode().getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                String nodeName = node.getNodeName();
                String nodeValue = node.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                addValueToRequestHeader(requestHeader, nodeName, nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return requestHeader;
}

private void addValueToRequestHeader(RequestHeader requestHeader, String nodeName, String nodeValue) {
    log.info("Start addValueToRequestHeader for nodeName : {} and nodeValue : {}", nodeName, nodeValue);
    switch (nodeName) {
        case "ns:name":
            requestHeader.setActivityName(nodeValue);
            break;
        case "ns:lastname":
            if (nodeValue.equalsIgnoreCase(RequestMessageType.NOTIFICATION.value())) {
                requestHeader.setMsgType(RequestMessageType.NOTIFICATION);
            } else {
                requestHeader.setMsgType(RequestMessageType.REQUEST);
            }
            break;
        case "ns:middlename":
            requestHeader.setSenderURI(nodeValue);
            break;   
        default:
            break;
    }
 
}
```